# Volatile data in Solr

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have an index of documents which is distributed over several shards and replicas. The size is ca. 40 mil and I expect it to grow

**Problem**: Users add information to these documents, which they change quite frequently. They need it to be integrated in search syntax, e.g. `funny and cool and cat:interesting`. Where cat would be a volatile data set

As far as I know neither Solr nor Lucene support "true update", that means that I have to reindex the whole set of changed documents again. Thus I need to connect it to external data source such as relational database.

I did it in Lucene with extendable search (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/index.html). The algorithm was pretty easy:

1. Preprosess query by adding "_" to all external fields
2. Map these fields to classes
3. Each class extends org.apache.lucene.search.Filter class and converts ids to a bitset by overriding public `public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(AtomicReaderContext context, Bits acceptDocs) throws IOException`:

   ```
       ResultSet set = state.executeQuery();        
       OpenBitSet bitset = new OpenBitSet();
       while (set.next()) {
           bitset.set(set.getInt("ID"));
       }
   ```
4. Then by extending org.apache.lucene.queryparser.ext.ParserExtension, I override parse like this:

   `public Query parse(ExtensionQuery eq) throws ParseException{
       String cat= eq.getRawQueryString();
       Filter filter = _cache.getFilter(cat);
       return new ConstantScoreQuery(filter);
   }`
5. Extend org.apache.lucene.queryparser.ext.Extensions using add method and done.

But **HOW** to do this in Solr?

I found couple of suggestions:

1. Using external field (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/ExternalFileField.html)
2. NRS (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NearRealtimeSearch) which looks a little bit under construction to me.

Any ideas how to do it in Solr? Maybe there are some code examples?

Please, consider also that Im kinda new to Solr.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Solr 4.x releases all support [Atomic Update](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates) which I believe may satisfy your needs.

Comment: thank you, but what about performance? Is it much better then removing and adding the document back again? and do i need to pass all fields to the request? Sry if questions make no sense

Comment: You will only pass the field(s) that need to updated and the update modifier (add, set, delete) to apply. Please refer to the documentation for this as well as the limitations and caveats to this functionality. As far as performance, you will need to test that for your specific scenario as there are too many variables with each persons Solr implementation to be able to make any broad performance statements.

Comment: One more question, what if I dont have all fields stored? For example I store text of the document separately in the database due to performance issues.

Comment: A current limitation of Atomic Updates is that all fields in your schema need to be stored for it to work. So in this case you would not be able to leverage Atomic Update, Sorry.